# Error: Unable to move the cache: Access is denied, when using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, caching

I'm trying to use selenium (in Python) to scrape a website, however, when I start the chrome web driver, it tries to load the page for a few seconds, and then closes the window and returns the following error message:

```
[22424:18188:0531/121110.652:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
[22424:18188:0531/121110.653:ERROR:cache_util.cc(139)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[22424:18188:0531/121110.653:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[22424:18188:0531/121110.653:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
Opening in existing browser session.
```

I 'm using a custom profile when loading the page. My `ChromeOptions` look like:

```
OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
OPTIONS.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=OPTIONS)

# rest of code
```

P.S.

1) I don't have any Chrome processes running in the background. I'm using Firefox in the background though.

2) It worked for the first few times, It stopped working just now.

Comment: There are no errors with ChromeOptions.

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: Need to see full code

Comment: Probably it's because you have other Chrome windows open. Try to close them and retry.

Answer (score 2):

Close all Chrome Tasks from Task Manager. Mainly including the name "Google" or "Google Crash handler / reporter". It will work

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error when trying to deploy in AWS. The issue was that I was starting the script on vscode terminal, which somehow didn't have permission. It worked when I tried on command prompt outside of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your drive is quite after testcase

something like:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=OPTIONS)
try{
  #your code
} catch (Exception e) {
  #raise exception
} finally {
  driver.quit(); # This is imp to quit driver
}
```

You can try driver.close() too but that only close current window. If you don't want to use try catch block do like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=OPTIONS)

  # rest of your code
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -4):

Seems like you are missing the guava dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How is this related at all to the question? The question is about python but your answer is about Maven. Also I'm confused how guava comes into this.